# One page available at two addresses .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

**Initial data:**

The site has some page:

```
 http://domen.com/index.php?act=rules
```

Decided to change the view of the links in the address bar of the browser to:

```
 http://domen.com/rules
```

I make it a rule:

```
 RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]{3,10})$ index.php?act=$1 [L]
```

Everything works fine, there are no problems. (in the browser addresses bar the address you entered *http://domen.com/rules* and the script receives the ***act=rules*** parameter, because the page script uses it).

**Problem:**

The problem is that the same page is now available at these two different addresses.

How to make changing the addresses bar when entering at:

```
http://domen.com/index.php?act=rules to http://domen.com/rules
```

also with the preservation of the ***act=rules*** parameter? (because it is used in a script).

What rule can be used?

Or maybe is the logic itself wrong?

Tell me where to look. Thanks!

Comment: Can you make `act=` optional like `^(?:act=)?([A-Za-z0-9]{3,10})$` ? And perhaps exclude the redirect when you enter rules `^(?!rules\b)(?:act=)?([A-Za-z0-9]{3,10})$` https://regex101.com/r/F70Djt/1

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But the first line 
(RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]{3,10})$ index.php?act=$1 [L]) solves this problem. 
When I enter the address http://domen.com/rules in the browser, this address stay in that view in the url bar, according to the original idea, the redirect does not need to be disabled here. The rule does not change the view of the address. The rule only passes parameters.
My problem is that I can't find a rule that would change the address in the browser url bar from this: http://domen.com/index.php?act=rules to this http://domen.com/rules and not get a loop and an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question you simply want to add a rule to redirect the original URL to the rewritten one?

This should do what you want:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^act=([A-Za-z0-9]{3,10})$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /%1 [QSD,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9]{3,10})$ /index.php?act=$1 [END]
```

It is a good idea to start with a `R=302` *temporary* redirection. And to only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as desired. That prevents nasty caching issues.

You can implement those rules in the http server's host configuration (preferred place). Or, if you do not have access to that, you can use a *distributed* configuration file (".htaccess").

Comment: Yes, understand right.
Thank you. Tested. When added to .htaccess
the second rule, third line causes a loop

Comment: Maybe something can be done to avoid looping?

Comment: Change the `L` flag in the last rule to an `END` flag. I updated the answer accordingly.